# Input elements show saved user login informations at registration page

Tags: forms

I have a ***registration page*** with 10 `input` fields (firstname, lastname, password, etc.)

I have a ***login page*** with a login `form` (username and password) `input` fields.

When a user does a login on the login page, the webbrowser (Firefox 24 / Windows) asks if it should save the login informations. When the login informations are saved, the user doesn't have to write the login informations again into the input fields when he wants to login again.

When the user goes to the registration page, his saved login informations from the login page are in the form / inputs of the registrations page.

How can I disable this at all browsers?
Or how can I set the option that the user can not save the login informations at the first login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

`autocomplete="off"` does the trick and the problem is gone.